How to wait until file open in the editor
I am writing test case in swtbot for editor, when file is opening in the editor it’s taking some time like 3 to 4 seconds so test case not waiting for editor open so i am getting error so i just want to add wait condition so it should wait for editor open and the go to the next step.
Matcher withPartName = withPartName("title");// passing tilte of editor which is come when file is open in the editor.
Matcher matcher = allOf(IsInstanceOf.instanceOf(IEditorReference.class), withPartName);
bot.waitUntilWidgetAppears(waitForEditor(matcher));

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
